# store matrix data in SQLite for fast retrieval in R

Tags: sql, r

I have 48 matrices of dimensions 1,000 rows and 300,000 columns where each column has a respective ID, and each row is a measurement at one time point. Each of the 48 matrices is of the same dimension and their column IDs are all the same.

The way I have the matrices stored now is as RData objects and also as text files.  I guess for SQL I'd have to transpose and store by ID, and in such case now the matrix would be of dimensions 300,000 rows and 1,000 columns.

I guess if I transpose it a small version of the data would look like this:

```
id1 1.5 3.4 10 8.6 .... 10 (with 1,000 columns, and 30,0000 rows now)
```

I want to store them in a way such that I can use R to retrieve a few of the rows (~ 5 to 100 each time).

The general strategy I have in mind is as follows:

(1) Create a database in sqlite3 using R that I will use to store the matrices (in different tables)

For file 1 to 48 (each file is of dim 1,000 rows and 300,000 columns):

(2) Read in file into R

(3) Store the file as a matrix in R

(4) Transpose the matrix (now its of dimensions 300,000 rows and 1,000 columns).  Each row now is the unique id in the table in sqlite.

(5) Dump/write the matrix into the sqlite3 database created in (1) (dump it into a new table probably?)

Steps 1-5 are to create the DB.

Next, I need step 6 to read-in the database:

(6) Read some rows (at most 100 or so at a time) into R as a (sub)matrix.

A simple example code doing steps 1-6 would be best.

Some Thoughts:

I have used SQL before but it was mostly to store tabular data where each column had a name, in this case each column is just one point of the data matrix, I guess I could just name it col1 ... to col1000? or there are better tricks?

If I look at: http://sandymuspratt.blogspot.com/2012/11/r-and-sqlite-part-1.html they show this example:

```
 dbSendQuery(conn = db,
       "CREATE TABLE School
       (SchID INTEGER,
        Location TEXT,
        Authority TEXT,
        SchSize TEXT)")
```

But in my case this would look like:

```
 dbSendQuery(conn = db,
       "CREATE TABLE mymatrixdata
       (myid TEXT,
        col1 float,
        col2 float,
.... etc.....
        col1000 float)")
```

I.e., I have to type in col1 to ... col1000 manually, that doesn't sound very smart.  This is where I am mostly stuck.  Some code snippet would help me.

Then, I need to dump the text files into the SQLite database?  Again, unsure how to do this from R.

Seems I could do something like this:

```
setwd(<directory where to save the database>)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="myDBname")
mymatrix.df = read.table(<full name to my text file containing one of the matrices>)
mymatrix = as.matrix(mymatrix.df)
```

Here I need to now the coe on how to dump this into the database...

Finally,

How to fast retrieve the values (without having to read the entire matrices each time) for some of the rows (by ID) using R?

From the tutorial it'd look like this:

```
sqldf("SELECT id1,id2,id30 FROM mymatrixdata", dbname = "Test2.sqlite")
```

But it the id1,id2,id30 are hardcoded in the code and I need to dynamically obtain them.  I.e., sometimes i may want id1, id2, id10, id100; and another time i may want id80, id90, id250000, etc.

Something like this would be more approp for my needs:

```
cols.i.want = c("id1","id2","id30")
sqldf("SELECT cols.i.want FROM mymatrixdata", dbname = "Test2.sqlite")
```

Again, unsure how to proceed here.  Code snippets would also help.

A simple example would help me a lot here, no need to code the whole 48 files, etc. just a simple example would be great!

Note: I am using Linux server, SQlite 3 and R 2.13 (I could update it as well).

Comment: You might want to look at [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/moin).  If you're used to working with SQL, see these [hints for SQL users](http://www.pytables.org/moin/HintsForSQLUsers).

Comment: @ChrisP they look amazing, though my collaborator just updated me that we need them in R cause all the processing code was done in R... but great suggestion, i had change the question to R/sql.

Comment: You can work with HDF5 also from R with the h5r package

Comment: And there is [sqldf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/sqldf.pdf‎) -- to manipulate data frames with an SQL-type syntax.

Comment: @KarstenW. and hd1 these recs look amazing, thanks a lot.  If you find more time and can put a simple example related to my requirements would be great... looking into them, thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments the poster explained that it is only necessary to retrieve specific rows, not columns:

```
library(RSQLite)

m <- matrix(1:24, 6, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:6], NULL)) # test matrix

con <- dbConnect(SQLite()) # could add dbname= arg.  Here use in-memory so not needed.
dbWriteTable(con, "m", as.data.frame(m)) # write
dbGetQuery(con, "create unique index mi on m(row_names)")

# retrieve submatrix back as m2
m2.df <- dbGetQuery(con, "select * from m where row_names in ('A', 'C') 
            order by row_names")
m2 <- as.matrix(m2.df[-1])
rownames(m2) <- m2.df$row_names
```

Note that relational databases are set based and the order that the rows are stored in is not guaranteed.  We have used `order by row_names` to get out a specific order.  If that is not good enough then add a column giving the row index: 1, 2, 3, ... .

*REVISED* based on comments.

Comment: thanks a lot.  That looks like the way to go.  I should have been more clear though, each row (in the transposed matrix) has an ID and I would like to retrieve them by ID instead of by column/row number, would you mind changing the example for such case?

Comment: OK. Have added row and column id's.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am trying to follow the logic, Why do i need to store it as a triple?  I only need to retrieve specific rows, not specific columns, wouldn't it suffice to just store it as the matrix it is and have row IDs?

Comment: In that case its even easier. I have modified it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks so much, looks very nice now.  As a curiosity: I tried it with my data (1,000 by 300,000 matrix) and when I do: dbWriteTable(db, "mymat", as.data.frame(mymat)) it takes quite sometime (not sure why is slower than reading the RData file, guess cause it's writing to disk) and it uses more space than the RData file (not sure why should it use more space).  Just wondering, is there a way to store the objects in a more compressed and faster way in sqlite?

Comment: Also when I do dbGetQuery(db, "select * from mymat where row_names in ('myname10', 'myname100') order by row_names") it's extremely slow, is there a way to make this fast? This is the major part i need to be quick since i'll be doing this thousands of times.  Ideally this would be instantaneous.  I thought SQL stores the data as hash tables so retrieving by ID should be on the order of seconds or am i missing something?  thanks again.

Comment: RData format is optimized for R and does not have to include the capability of selective retrieval so you can't expect that storing and retrieval to a relational database will be as fast.  You can add an index to the rownames to make retrieval faster but you will spend additional time creating the index so total creation time will be slower.

Comment: Thanks again. Making creation time slower is ok w me bc it's not the bottleneck. Would u mind changing the answer so as to make the retrieval time as instantaneous as possible?

Comment: Just to add something more. Is there a way to store the data sorted and indexed by ID so the retrieval is almost instantaneous? I will be calling the database thousands of times. So if that's not the case I may need another solution it seems bc SQ might not have been a good design choice. Perhaps given your experience you might have other suggestions?

Comment: OK. `m` now has an index on `row_names`.  Regarding storing the data in a particular order this was already specifically discussed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  It is very fast now! I thought about it and shouldn't we also set the rowIDs as keys? they are unique and I think if we use them as key we could make it even better.  Sorry to keep pondering you with Qs but this has been so helpful!

Comment: Making the row id's into keys is similar to adding an index and a unique constraint.  You can get both of these by changing `create index` to `create unique index` above and then testing it out to see if it makes any difference.  I have made such a change in the `create` statement above.

Comment: Thanks, i'm just thinking ahead in the sense that if I append new rows I'll have to re-index the DB (am I right?), but i think if I have them as keys I wouldn't run into such problem

Comment: No.  It maintains the index once its set; however, insertion will be more time consuming with an index or key.